# How to change Document Title Size in Koma scrbook?

Tags: koma-script, titles, scrbook

[image: Main Title Page]

[image]

[image: extratitle]

I am using a few a features of Koma script's `\maketitle` command, namely `extratitle`, `frontispiece` and `lowertitleback`. I want all these features to remain.

I am trying to increase the font size of the main `\title` and `\subtitle`. They should be bigger than the half title on the extratitle page. I do not have an exact requirement as I've not been able to play with it. I guess the title needs to be a little larger than `\Huge`.

I have tried several ways but none worked.

First, I tried to use a method of defining a custom size (thanks to Danie Els).

```
\newcommand*{\TitleFont}{%
      \usefont{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{b}{n}%
      \fontsize{16}{20}%
      \selectfont}

\setkomafont{title}{\TitleFont\textbf}
```

I also tried the `\addtokomafont` command, didn't work either. There was no change to the font size.

Second, I tried the `titling` package:

```
\usepackage{titling}

\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE} 
\title{GOOD STUFF}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
```

Also, didn't work. It lost the earlier pages.

I also tried to define my own titlepage using the `\titlepage` enviroment, but `\maketitle` insists that `\title` is defined.

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \vspace*{4\baselineskip}
    \begin{center}
        \usekomafont{title}\huge
        \hspace*{0.36in}
        \textbf{\Huge GOOD STUFF\newline}
        \hspace*{0.2in}
        \textbf{\Large Reconciling Your Mama and Your Papa}
        \title{GOOD STUFF}
        \subtitle{Reconciling Your Mama and Your Papa}
        
        \vfill
        Centre of The Universe\\ %Jack edit6, replaced '\newline with \\
        The University of Uncommon Sense\\
        2021
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

I have attached an image as to how the first few pages should look. I've spent hours trying to find out how to increase with title size without losing the other features. I've read the KOMA guide, the Mittelbach LaTeX guide and googled but no luck.

And the MWE:

```
\documentclass[titlepage=firstiscover,size=160mm:234mm,DIV=calc]{scrbook} 

\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{txfonts} 
\usepackage{upgreek} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{CJKutf8} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand*{\TitleFont}{%
    \usefont{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{b}{n}%
    \fontsize{56}{20}%
    \selectfont}

\setkomafont{title}{\TitleFont} 

    \title{\centering\textbf{GOOD STUFF\newline}} 
    \subtitle{Reconciling Your Mama and Your Papa} 
    \author{Jack} %Jack edit4
    \publishers{Centre of The Universe\\ 
        The University of Uncommon Sense\\
    2021} %Jack edit5
    \date{} %Jack edit4


\begin{document}

\frontmatter   

\extratitle{   
    \vspace*{4\baselineskip}
        \begin{center}
            \usekomafont{title}\huge
            \hspace*{0.36in}
            \textbf{\Huge GOOD STUFF\newline}
            \hspace*{0.2in}
            \textbf{\Large Reconciling Your Mama and Your Papa}
            \title{GOOD STUFF}
            \subtitle{Reconciling Your Mama and Your Papa}
        \end{center}
    \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
    \blindtext \newline
    \vspace*{\baselineskip}
    
    \textbf{Author Name} \blindtext
}

 % jacked 03 March to add CBS Publications
\frontispiece{ 
    \parindent=0pt
    \setlength{\parskip}{5pt}
    \centering\textbf{\Large Publication Series}
    \begin{flushleft}
        
        \textbf{Scholars}
        
        \textit{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\ 
        yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
        
        \textit{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\ 
        yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
        
        \textit{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\ 
        yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
        
        \textit{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\ 
        yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
        
        \textit{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\ 
        yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
        
    \end{flushleft}
}

\begin{comment}

\begin{titlepage}
    \vspace*{4\baselineskip}
    \begin{center}
        \usekomafont{title}\huge
        \hspace*{0.36in}
        \textbf{\Huge GOOD STUFF\newline}
        \hspace*{0.2in}
        \textbf{\Large Reconciling Your Mama and Your Papa}
        \title{GOOD STUFF}
        \subtitle{Reconciling Your Mama and Your Papa}
        
        \vfill
        Centre of The Universe\\ %Jack edit6, replaced '\newline with \\
        The University of Uncommon Sense\\
        2021
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{comment}
\lowertitleback{    % jacked 26 Feb to add copyright-publisher's block
    
    \begin{flushleft}
        
        Published in by School of Hard Knocks\\
        The University of Uncommon Sense\\
        2021\\
        \vspace*{\baselineskip}
        © Centre of The Universe,\\
        The University of Uncommon Sense\\
        All Rights Reserved\\
        \vspace*{\baselineskip}
        ISBN: 978-999-99999-9-2 (Hardcover)\\
        ISBN: 978-999-99999-9-9 (e-book)
        
    \end{flushleft}
}

\maketitle 

\begin{center}
    \noindent
    What is to prevent us, then, from hiding this under my pillow?\\
    
    Arisnotle, 
\end{center}


\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

Sorry, but the images didn't upload/appear how'd I'd expected.

Comment: I saw in one of the related posts (possibly by Johannes) that maketitle is very overrated. It certainly didn't give me the flexibility that I wanted.
So I removed the maketitle and made each title page with titlepage environment. There is a commented out example in the above MWE.
Then I struggled with every titlepage starting on the recto side, whereas I wanted the publications list and copyright block to appear on the verso side. So those I just removed the titlepage environment. Then they were no longer treated as a new chapter, so appeared on the verso side.
Job done!

Comment: Please see my added answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, there are some missunderstandings ...

Let us have a look to the following MWE (important codes are marked with `<======`):

```
\documentclass[%
  titlepage=firstiscover,
  size=160mm:234mm,
  DIV=calc
]{scrbook} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <====================== standard nowadays
\usepackage{blindtext} % <======================= to generate dummy text
\usepackage{showframe} % <========== to show the typing area and margins

\usepackage{hyperref} % <=========================== last called package


\newcommand{\HUGE}{\fontsize{56}{60}\selectfont} % <====================
\setkomafont{title}{\HUGE\bfseries} % <=================================

\title{GOOD STUFF} 
\subtitle{Reconciling Your Mama and Your Papa} 
\author{Jack} %Jack edit4
\publishers{Centre of The Universe\\ 
  The University of Uncommon Sense\\
  2021} %Jack edit5
\date{} %Jack edit4


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\maketitle 

\begin{center}
    \noindent
    What is to prevent us, then, from hiding this under my pillow?\\
    
    Arisnotle, 
\end{center}

\pagebreak

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

There I defined the command `\HUGE` with `\newcommand{\HUGE}{\fontsize{56}{60}\selectfont}`. Now we can use it to define the fontsize for the title of the document with `\setkomafont{title}{\HUGE\bfseries}`. Then follows the definitions for the title text, subtitle text etc.

The result is

[image: resulting pdf]

where the lines marks the typing area and margins. As you can see the title is centered in the typing area ...

To get all the pages (extratitle, frontispiece etc.) you wanted in your question we have to change your code to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
  titlepage=firstiscover,
  size=160mm:234mm,
  DIV=calc
]{scrbook} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <====================== standard nowadays
\usepackage{blindtext} % <======================= to generate dummy text
\usepackage{showframe} % <========== to show the typing area and margins

\usepackage{hyperref} % <=========================== last called package

\newcommand{\HUGE}{\fontsize{56}{60}\selectfont} % <====================
\title{GOOD STUFF}

\begin{document}

\extratitle{%
  \vspace*{4\baselineskip}
  \begin{center}
    \HUGE\textbf{GOOD STUFF}\newline % <===============================
    \Large\textbf{Reconciling Your Mama and Your Papa}
 
    Extratitle
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
  \blindtext \newline
  \vspace*{\baselineskip}
    
  \textbf{Author Name} \blindtext
}

\frontispiece{% 
    \parindent=0pt
    \setlength{\parskip}{5pt}
    \centering\textbf{\Large Publication Series}
    \begin{flushleft}
        
        \textbf{Scholars}
        
        \textit{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\ 
        yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
        
        \textit{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\ 
        yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
        
        \textit{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\ 
        yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
        
        \textit{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\ 
        yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
        
        \textit{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\ 
        yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
        
    \end{flushleft}
}

\begin{titlepage}
  \vspace*{4\baselineskip}
  \begin{center}
    \HUGE\textbf{GOOD STUFF}\newline % <================================
    \Large\textbf{Reconciling Your Mama and Your Papa}

    \vfill
    Centre of The Universe\\ %Jack edit6, replaced '\newline with \\
    The University of Uncommon Sense\\
    2021
  \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\lowertitleback{    % jacked 26 Feb to add copyright-publisher's block
    
    \begin{flushleft}
        
        Published in by School of Hard Knocks\\
        The University of Uncommon Sense\\
        2021\\
        \vspace*{\baselineskip}
        © Centre of The Universe,\\
        The University of Uncommon Sense\\
        All Rights Reserved\\
        \vspace*{\baselineskip}
        ISBN: 978-999-99999-9-2 (Hardcover)\\
        ISBN: 978-999-99999-9-9 (e-book)
        
    \end{flushleft}
}

\frontmatter % <========================================================
\maketitle 

\begin{center}
    \noindent
    What is to prevent us, then, from hiding this under my pillow?\\
    
    Arisnotle, 
\end{center}


\pagebreak

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter % <=========================================================

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

resulting in two titlepages:

[image: first title page]

and the second one:

[image: second page]

and all the other pages ... Important code changings are marked with `<======` ...